# Java: InputStream read() returns a byte bigger than 127?

Tags: java, io, int, byte

I've this code:

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
int b;
while ((b = is.read()) != -1)
{
   System.out.println(b);
}
```

A byte its range is `-128` until `+127`.
But one of the printed bytes is `210`.

Is this the result of converting the read `byte` to an `int`?
(So that the negatif `byte` becomes a positif `int`)
If so, can I do the same (with an `OutputStream`) by converting an `int` to a `byte`?

Thanks,
Martijn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually `read` returns an integer..

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException
```

so it's implictly casted to be unsigned byte by storing it in an int.

As stated in documentation:

> Reads the next byte of data from the
>   input stream. The value byte is
>   returned as an int in the range 0 to
>   255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned.

Think about the fact that if it's a signed byte then `-1` couldn't be used as end of stream value.

For `OutputStream` you have

```
public abstract void write(int b) throws IOException
```

and as stated by documentation implementation will take 8 low order bits of the integer passed..