# Why that Java I/O use "int" but not "byte"/"char" when read/write a single byte/character?

Tags: java, io, char, int, byte

Why does Java I/O use `int` but not `byte`/`char` when reading and writing a single byte/character. The methods in streams and readers are:

**InputStream**

```
abstract  int read()
```

**OutputStream**

```
abstract void write(int b)
```

**Reader**

```
int read()
```

**Writer**

```
void write(**int** c)
```

---

And it uses `byte`/`char` when read/write some number of bytes or characters into an array. Why `int` when the data is a single byte/character? Why not `byte`/`char`?

**InputStream**

```
int read(byte[] b)   
int** read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

**OutputStream**

```
void write(byte[] b)   
void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)
```

**Reader**

```
int read(char[] cbuf) 
abstract  int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)
```

**Writer**

```
void write(char[] cbuf) 
abstract  void write(**char**[] cbuf, int off, int len)
```

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186069/java-inputstream-read-returns-a-byte-bigger-than-127?rq=1

Comment: Close because it's opinion based? This is nothing of the sort. It has a very concrete, real answer that is entirely scientific. If anything, it should be closed as a duplicate of the question @BinyaminSharet linked.