# Why do OutputStreams and InputStreams take and return ints that represent byte values?

Tags: java, io, stream

All sublasses of `InputStream` return an `int` representing the value of the byte read. Same for all `OutputStream` subclasses, that take as arguments to the `write` method an `int` instead of a `byte`.

Two questions:

1- Why is that?

2- If I want to write the byte 10110101 to an output stream, how can I programatically convert it to an int before passing it into `write`? Same for when I receive an int from an input stream, how can I convert it to a `byte`?

Comment: Related: [Java: InputStream read() returns a byte bigger than 127?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186069/java-inputstream-read-returns-a-byte-bigger-than-127)

Answer (score 1):

`InputStream.read()` returns an `int` because that's an easy way to differentiate between valid data (values in range 0..255) and end-of-file (-1). That's covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659659/why-does-inputstreamread-return-an-int-and-not-a-byte).

`OutputStream.write()` takes an `int` because otherwise you'd have to cast the value from `InputStream.read()`.

If you have a `byte` in the range -128..-1 and want to convert it to an `int` in the range 128..255, you use a mask:

```
byte b = (byte)0xCD;
int i = b & 0xFF;
```

Comment: In practice, the mask is used irrespective of the value. It doesn't hurt for non-negative byte values. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Because they need to return -1 for EOS. As a side effect this results in returning unsigned values (even though bytes are signed in Java).